# Finding a timedelta in pandas dataframe based upon specific values in one column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, crosstab

I have a dataframe where i wish to compute the number of days (timedelta) that a unique asset remained installed. The sample input dataframe is as follows

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2007-11-01','2012-03-02','2012-03-02','2013-04-01','2013-04-01','2017-11-15','2017-11-15'], 'action':['installed','installed','removed','installed','removed','installed','removed'], 'asset_alphnum':['A-3724','A-3534','A-3724','A2732','A-3534','A-2007','A2732']})
```

Outputs:

[image]

I have tried pd.crosstab

```
pd.crosstab(df.asset_alphnum, [df.Date, df.action])
```

outputs
[image]

However I cannot work out how to take it from here. Somehow need to collapse the hierarchical index and subract one date from the next.

Any guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only ever have one install date and one removed date for each ID, you can do it with a pivot table, by using max (or min or any other aggregating function) on the date values.

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])  # Converting strings to datetimes
df = df.pivot_table(index="asset_alphnum", columns="action", values="Date", aggfunc=max)  # max is just an example, most aggfuncs will work if there's only ever one date
df["time_installed"] = df["removed"] - df["installed"]  # timedelta column
```

Which outputs this:

| asset_alphnum | installed | removed | time_installed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A-2007 | 2017-11-15 00:00:00 | NaT | NaT |
| A-3534 | 2012-03-02 00:00:00 | 2013-04-01 00:00:00 | 395 days 00:00:00 |
| A-3724 | 2007-11-01 00:00:00 | 2012-03-02 00:00:00 | 1583 days 00:00:00 |
| A2732 | 2013-04-01 00:00:00 | 2017-11-15 00:00:00 | 1689 days 00:00:00 |

Comment: that is fantastic, thank you. I assume passing aggfunc=max would mean taking largest values where there are duplicates of install/remove for the same id?

Comment: max would take the largest (i.e. latest) date for both installed and removed, so if you had multiple installed/removed in there it would only give you the time installed for the latest installation.

Comment: ok thanks. it hasn't worked on my actual df. In reality I have multiple install and multiple remove dates for any ID

Comment: You would get some odd values if you have multiple installs and removes for the same id, but not an even number of each. You'd end up with a negative value in time_installed.

Comment: If you want total install time, you should refer to a previous question of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62521934/

Answer (score 1):

create two columns installed and remove using an apply.  Then use the dataframe cross tab to count frequencies

```
date=['2007-11-01', '2012-03-02', '2012-03-02',
'2013-04-01', '2013-04-01', '2017-11-15', '2017-11-15']
action=['installed', 'installed', 'removed', 'installed','removed','installed','removed']
asset_alphnum=['A-3724','A3534','A-3724','A2732','A-3534','A-2007','A2732']

df=pd.DataFrame({'date':date, 'action':action,'asset_alphnum':asset_alphnum})
df.set_index('date')
df['installed']=df['action'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='installed' else 0)
df['removed']=df['action'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='removed' else 0)
df.drop('action',axis=1)
print(df)
print(pd.crosstab(df.asset_alphnum, [df.date]))
output:
date           2007-11-01  2012-03-02  2013-04-01  2017-11-15
asset_alphnum                                                
A-2007                  0           0           0               1
A-3534                  0           0           1           0
A-3724                  1           1           0           0
A2732                   0           0           1           1
A3534                   0           1           0           0
```